# DEAP mutation function receives parameters out of order

Tags: deap

I'm struggling to get the **deap.tools.mutUniformInt** mutation function to work. To isolate the issue for this SO question, I changed line 62 of examples/ga/onemax.py from

```
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.05)
```

to

```
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutUniformInt, 0, 1, indpb=0.05)
```

The onemax.py example now fails:

```
C:\Users\mshiv\DEAP>python onemax.py
Start of evolution
  Evaluated 300 individuals
-- Generation 1 --
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mshiv\DEAP\onemax.py", line 161, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\mshiv\DEAP\onemax.py", line 128, in main
    toolbox.mutate(mutant)
  File "C:\Users\mshiv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\deap\tools\mutation.py", line 159, in mutUniformInt
    size = len(individual)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Both mutators should operate on an *Individual*, which is defined in onemax.py to be a list, so why does **mutFlipBit** work, but **mutUniformInt** seems to receive the *Individual* parameter as an int, not a list?

Poking around in the DEAP code, I found that **mutUniformInt** receives the parameters out of order, i.e. they are passed in as (low, up, individual, indpb) whereas the function itself is defined as

def mutUniformInt(individual, low, up, indpb):

Am I registering this mutation function incorrectly?

Source of the onemax example I altered:

https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/ga/onemax.py

Answer (score 0):

NVM - found the answer here:

https://groups.google.com/g/deap-users/c/4sw2_Al4YFI/m/EvUiq70IBAAJ

The correct syntax should have been:

```
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutUniformInt, low=0, up=1, indpb=0.05)
```